# $P(n)$ is product of all digits of $n$. Find all $n$ such that $P(n)$ = $n^2−10n−22$.

Tags: number-theory

> $P(n)$ is defined as product of all digits of $n$ (decimal
>   representation). Find all $n$ such that $P(n)$ = $n^2−10n−22$.

I know the answer, which I will post later on in few days, but I want to see if someone has different approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $n$ is a $k$-digit number, then $n \ge 10^{k-1}$ and $P(n)\le9^k \le 9\cdot10^{k-1}$; in particular, $P(n) \le9n$. Thus if $P(n)=n^2-10n-22$, then $n^2-19n-22\le0$, which implies that $n\le20$. Checking the numbers from $1$ to $20$ individually reveals that $n=12$ is the only solution.

Comment: Yes, my version of the proof was similar, using induction by number of digits to prove upper limit of p(n). Ii am accepting this as the answer.